# Using cython/numba for Pandas groupby aggregation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With `DataFrame.apply` it is possible to use `raw=True` which causes the applied function to be called with a Numpy array, allowing for speedus by writing the function in Cython using JITint it with Numba.

Is the same possible with `DataFrame.groupby().agg`?

Comment: My impression is that if you call `agg` with a functionality that exists in Numpy, it will default to using arrays, but if you supply your own func it will use a Series - but not certain about this. See the source [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L237).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible.

`GroupBy.agg` accepts a single parameter `func`, which is a callable (the function you want to run). Any additional args or kwargs are passed to your `func`.

see: [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html)